# shiny filter applied to 2 outputs

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a dashboard in shiny with 2 visualizations (datatable and bargraph) that will allow the user to apply the same filters to both visualizations simultaneously.  I tried using the solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001211/filter-data-frame-for-use-in-multiple-renderplot-functions) but I guess I am missing something.  "Data5" is the name of the data frame I am using to populate. Any help would be appreciated.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dt <- data5

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


data <- reactive({data5
    if (input$year != "All"){
      data <- data[data5$year == input$year,]
    }
   if (input$month != "All"){
      data <- data[data5$month == input$month,]
    }
   if (input$partner_name != "All"){
      data <- data[data5$partner_name == input$partner_name,]
    }
    if (input$cube_title != "All"){
      data <- data[data5$cube_title == input$cube_title,]
    }

  })

  #plots
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    data
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=subset(data5,cube_title=="Leads"), aes(x=month,y=f0_)) + geom_bar(fill="blue", stat = "identity") + ylab("Leads") + ggtitle("Leads")
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=subset(data5,cube_title==c("CommunityProfileViews","HomeProfileViews")), aes(x=month,y=f0_)) + geom_bar(fill="blue", stat = "identity") + ylab("Profile Views") + ggtitle("Profile Views")

  })

})
```

**ui.R**

```
dashboardPage(
  skin = "blue",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
     ( 
          selectInput("year", 
                      "Year:", 
                      c("All", 
                        unique(as.character(data5$year))))
      ),
      ( 
          selectInput("month", 
                      "Month:", 
                      c("All", 
                        unique(as.character(data5$month))))
      ),
      (
          selectInput("partner_name", 
                      "Partner:", 
                      c("All", 
                        unique(as.character(data5$partner_name))))
                        ),
      (
          selectInput("cube_title", 
                      "Metric:", 
                      c("All", 
                        unique(as.character(data5$cube_title))))
      )        
    ),

  dashboardBody(


     tabsetPanel(id = "tabSelected",
                tabPanel("Charts", plotOutput("plot1"), 
                box(plotOutput("plot2"))),
                tabPanel("DataTable", dataTableOutput("table1"))
    )

               )
            )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Issue 1:** reactive returns a function, not an object. So we need to call `data()`, not `data`, in your `renderDataTable` and `renderPlot` functions

**Issue 2:** you need to put `data()` in your render functions. Currently, it is calling `data5`, which is not reactive:

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    Temp <- data()
    ggplot(data=subset(Temp,cube_title=="Leads"), aes(x=month,y=f0_)) + geom_bar(fill="blue", stat = "identity") + ylab("Leads") + ggtitle("Leads")
})
```

**Issue 3:** Your reactive function returns an assignment call. I would do this more like:

```
data <- reactive({ #The data5 that was here is not necessary
  temp <- data5 
  if (input$year != "All"){
    temp <- temp[temp$year == input$year,]
  }
  if (input$month != "All"){
    temp <- temp[temp$month == input$month,]
  }
  if (input$partner_name != "All"){
    temp <- temp[temp$partner_name == input$partner_name,]
  }
  if (input$cube_title != "All"){
    temp <- temp[temp$cube_title == input$cube_title,]
  }
  return(temp)

})
```

so that now when we call `data()`, we return our filtered `data.frame`

**Issue 4**: (albeit less of an issue) I would avoid using `data` as an object name. It means something else and can often get confusing when reading code. Use the safer `DT` or something else. You can always check if a name is in use by typing `exists("NameToCheck")` in the console.

[Suggested Reading](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/)

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work when calling a function instead of an object.  When I tried, I got an error of object "cube_title" not found.  I am not sure if I added your suggestions correctly.

**server.ui**
    `datainput <- reactive({
     if (input$year != "All")
     {data5[data5$year == input$year,]...
<br/>
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({`
    ggplot(data=subset(datainput(),cube_title=="Leads"),
    aes(x=month,y=f0_)) + geom_bar(fill="blue", stat = "identity") +
    ylab("Leads") + ggtitle("Leads")
    })`

Comment: @ericb no way to know without knowing what your data is like. call `print(datainput())` within renderPlot and see what displays. If there is no column called `cube_input`, you will get the error you saw

Comment: Did that.  Got a blank box in the dashboard and "NULL" in the console.

Comment: @ericb are you no longer getting the "cube_title" error?  It is very difficult for me to reproduce + troubleshoot your error without your `data5`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry about that.  Here is a dummy example:

`year <- c('2014','2015','2015','2013','2014')`
`month <- c('Jan','Feb','Feb','Dec','Oct')`
`partner_name <- c('1','2','3','1','3')`
`cube_title <- c('leads','calls','check','store','go')`
`data7 <- cbind(year,month,partner_name,cube_title)`

Comment: @ericb maybe try `data7` in your reactive call instead of `data5`

Comment: I'm sorry, I created the dummy data with the incorrect dateframe name.  I'm still using data5.

Comment: @ericb might be an issue with ggplot trying to interpret a function. Try my edit above

Comment: I see your change, but it didn't make a difference.  I am not sure why the datatable also wouldn't work if the plot was incorrectly formatted.  Also, when I switch the data.frame of data5 back into the plot instead of the function of data(), it works.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @ericb one more change, this time to the reactive function

Comment: Tried that.  Everything now renders a plot or table, but the filters no longer work.

**yikes!**